# Create a FAT16 filesystem with DiskPart

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, diskpart, fat16

I need to create a FAT16 image via a batch script. I am trying to get DiskPart on Windows 10 to create a FAT16 image and am running into some issues.

How I am attempting to create the image

```
diskpart
create vdisk file=C:\filesystem.vhd type=fixed maximum=17
select vdisk file=C:\filesystem.vhd
attach vdisk
create partition primary
select partition 1
active
format FS=FAT label=dfs
assign letter=w

[Copy Files over]

detach vdisk
exit
```

The problem is:

- If the number of files coppied over is small, diskpart will create a fat12 volume. How do I force diskpart to always create a FAT16 filesystem?
- When I open the image in a hex-editor, it doesn't really look like a FAT16 filesystem at all. It seems like everything is offset with some data at the start. Not too sure what is going on. I have tried using qemu-img to convert the vhd to a raw img and still the format does not appear to follow the layout of a FAT16 image. Is there some metadata I am missing here?

Comment: Did you try "format FS=FAT16" command?

Comment: Yes, it says filesystem not compatible or something to that effect.

Comment: Your question says Windows 10, but the tag says W7??? Evidently you will have to use a 3rd party utility to get it done.

Comment: Bottom of page....http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/diskpart-windows-10-1203.html